# zero to many relationship mapping to model

Tags: sql, sql-server, entity-framework

I'm having a bit of an issue mapping this out to my model. I have a Question model that represents (obviously) a question, and a QuestionType that represents the types of questions possible (text, multiple choice, list, multi-line text, and so on...).

The issue i'm having right now is trying to set the options associated with each of QuestionType Model back to the Question Model. So for example, if the QuestionType was a list type, and the list contained three elements, i'm trying to join those elements back on the Question model. The problem i'm having is that not all Questions need to have the QuestionOptions variable set. For example, for just a simple text question (not shown in code).

Any suggestions on how to achieve this?

**Question Model**

```
[Table("Questions")]
   public class Question {
      [Key]
      [DatabaseGeneratedAttribute(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
      public int QuestionId { get; set; }

      [Required]
      public String Question { get; set; }

      public int QuestionTypeId { get; set; }
      [ForeignKey("QuestionTypeId")]
      public virtual QuestionType QuestionType { get; set; }

      public virtual ICollection<QuestionOptions> QuestionOptions { get; set; }
   }
```

**QuestionType Model**

```
   [Table("QuestionTypes")]
   public class QuestionType {
      [Key]
      [DatabaseGeneratedAttribute(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
      public int QuestionTypeId { get; set; }

      [Required]
      public String QuestionType { get; set; }

   }
```

**QuestionOptions Model**

```
   public abstract class QuestionOptions {
      [Key]
      [DatabaseGeneratedAttribute(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
      public int OptionId { get; set; }

      public int? QuestionId { get; set; }
      [ForeignKey("QuestionId")]
      public virtual Question Question { get; set; }
   }

   [Table("questionType_List")]
   public class ListQuestion : QuestionOptions {
      [Required]
      public String Item { get; set; }
   }
```

**QuestionContext**

```
   public class QuestionContext : DbContext {
      public QuestionContext() : base("DefaultConnection") { }

      protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder) {
         Database.SetInitializer<QuestionContext>(null);

      public DbSet<Question> Questions { get; set; }
      public DbSet<QuestionType> QuestionTypes { get; set; }
      public DbSet<ListQuestion> ListQuestions { get; set; }
   }
```

Answer (score 1):

Personally I would have QuestionOptions for all questions, even if that was a blank entry in the table or perhaps some sort of identifier that allows you to know if its multi-line or single line text.

Comment: QuestionOptions is essentially the dynamic options for the QuestionType. So for a ListQuestion, the QuestionOptions would be the List of items for a list. To determine whether something is a multi-line or single line is determined by the QuestionType model, not by the QuestionOption model